# CSS 100% Height Div

Tags: html, css

Im making a website http://nebkat.com/beta/index.php and there is a grey background and a white background for content(see for yourself). The problem is that I cant set the white part to be 100% height. It only stays up to the title(Welcome...) and then it stops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heights specified in % will not be honored by the browser (edit: I mean to say they wont work the way you expect them to).

You need a clearing div inside your `<div id="container">` div. Here is where you should place it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="logo">...</div>
    <div id="menu">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <!-- HERE -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: They will — unless the parent element has a height that is treated as 'auto' (in which case the percentage is treated as auto too).

Comment: That means the parent's height must be specified in *px*? Right?

Comment: No. Any unit at all. The only restriction is that it can't be auto (and if it is a percentage then apply this paragraph to its parent (and so on, recursively)).

Answer (score 2):

set the height of your #container div to be 100% this should fix the problem (at least it will in firefox 3.6).

You should really install a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox, you can use it to 'live' modify css properties on websites.  it makes it really easy to figure out issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

give height as 100% for container div and that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

this answer should be updated with this one: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}

#container{
  height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you will use `min-height:100%;` or `min-height:500px`.

That can solve your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The `height: 100%` in CSS doesnt't work as you'd expect.

My solution would be to write some simple JavaScript which measures the available height, and then sets the div's height appropriately.
It should be pretty straightforward, but if you need any help, I'll put it together for you.:)

Comment: I know how to do this but the problem is that I dont want javascript to be doing something css. Having an old browser could make it look bad :-/