# Why this not working?

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm tring to create with jquery 5x3 squares.
This is my code:

## css:

```
#SmallNailArea
{
    position:relative;
    height:85%;
    width:100%;
}

.SmallNailLine
{
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    clear:both;
}

.SmallNail
{
    background-color:black;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
    margin:4%
}
```

## jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var length = 15;
var lineCounter = 0;
var dh = $(".SmallNail").height();
$(".SmallNail").css('width', dh + 'px');

for (var i=1;i<=length;i++)
{
    if ((i-1)%3==0)
    {
        lineCounter++;
        $("<div></div>").attr('class','SmallNailLine').appendTo("$(#SmallNailArea"));
    }
    $("<div></div>").attr('class','SmallNail').appendTo("$(#SmallNailLine").eq(lineCounter));
}

});
```

It seems that the jquery dosen't working at all.

When I put alert inside the for it does alerting the right values but nothing else happened.

```
for (var i=1;i<=length;i++)
{
    if ((i-1)%3==0)
    {
        alert(lineCounter);
        lineCounter++;
        $("<div></div>").attr('class','SmallNailLine').appendTo("$(#SmallNailArea"));
    }
    alert(i);
    $("<div></div>").attr('class','SmallNail').appendTo("$(#SmallNailLine").eq(lineCounter));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It'll be much easier for the good folks of SO to help you out when they can see your code in action.

Comment: You should really use a debugging tool. Every modern Web browser has such a tool built in. Usually they are called **Developer tools** or something similar and yes they are also usually buried in some menu so that the average user is not confused with it. You as a developer would however gain a lot from the error messages that would be without doubt printed in their javascript console.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet syntax is wrong:

```
appendTo("$(#SmallNailArea"));
```

It should be:

```
appendTo($("#SmallNailArea"));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think this logic can be better. Look [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/Y8uPg/1/). I don't know if that shows the result as you expected.

In jQuery you can create an element and get it after that this way:

`var newEl = $('<div></div>');`

Once you got it on `newEl` it's easier to manipulate it. So I've created the var `tmp` to keep the new element to append another element on it in sequence.

```
if ((i-1)%3==0)
{
    tmp = $("<div></div>").addClass('SmallNailLine');
    $("#SmallNailArea").append(tmp);
}
tmp.append($("<div></div>").addClass('SmallNail'));
```

I also moved this code ...

```
var dh = $(".SmallNail").height();
$(".SmallNail").css('width', dh + 'px');
```

...to the end cause the object `.SmallNail` isn't created on the beggining, where you've been calling it.

Another trick is set the `#SmallNailArea` with the `height` in pixels `height:100px;` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800511/css-100-height-div).

At last, but not less important, the error that @tymeJV showed, that is crucial for the code to work.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear and you didnt created any live example, but ...

I created [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EKLff/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = 15;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var $SmallNailLine;
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            $SmallNailLine = $('<div class="SmallNailLine" />');
            $SmallNailLine.appendTo("#SmallNailArea");
        }
        $('<div class="SmallNail" />').appendTo($SmallNailLine);
    }
});
```

Also you have to add `float: left;` in `.SmallNail`.